# Titanium module source code

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile, appcelerator-alloy, appcelerator-studio

I have [Securely module](https://github.com/benbahrenburg/Securely) installed.

It have `createProperties()` function inside, how can I jump to definition of this function?

I saw documentation, I just need straightforward source code of this function.

It has `libbencoding.securely.a` file, but there is no way I can uncompress it to view source code.

I tried a lot of options, but no luck.

Can I do it inside Appcelerator Studio, or any other IDE ?

Comment: just look at github?

Comment: @RenePot nope, all source code is inside libbencoding.securely.a in github also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source code is available. Have a look here: https://github.com/benbahrenburg/Securely/blob/master/Android/src/bencoding/securely/PropertiesProxy.java#L79

The libs e.g. `libbencoding.securely.so` are created during compiling. The (android) project can be build completely from the source.

`libbencoding.securely.a` is inside the binary iOS version of the module, while the source-code is available at https://github.com/benbahrenburg/Securely/tree/master/iOS

Comment: Thank you, but can you find createProperties() function declaration there ? I'm not https://github.com/benbahrenburg/Securely/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=createProperties&type=

Comment: its the linked function above. It is create[Filename-without-proxy] = createProperties(). You see `options.containsKey("identifier")` at line 98 which is one parameter and so on

Comment: Thank you very much!
Maybe you can help me with this question ?
It's all based on this question, i'm struggling for days..
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47326340/titanium-bencoding-keychain-decoding-in-swift

Comment: Sorry can't help you there. I haven't used the module and I'm not an iOS guy.

Comment: @DavidDavidoff don't forget to mark the answer as the solution